# Filtering of nodes in Views creteria

Tags: views

Can somebody tell me if node filtering within Views is done by using `node_load` then checking it's fields, or by first filtering out the node table rows and then loading nodes using `node_load`?

I'm going to have tons (100,000+) of nodes and every time a View does a `node_load` on all of them will be very slow operation.

I've no idea how slow it'd be loading 100,000 nodes using `node_load`.

Comment: why you want to use node_load in views you will get all fields ?